# Fixed width to CSV

Tags: csv, awk, fixed-width

I know how to use `awk` to change fixed width to CSV. What I have is a hard drive with a few thousand fixed width files. The all contain different column width formats, but it is "encoded" on the second line as:

```
Name           DOB      GENDER
============== ======== ======
JOHN DOE       19870130 M
MARY DOE       19850521 F
MARTY MCFLY    19790320 M
```

I want to convert ALL the files to CSV. I can write a program that reads in the first line and holds it for column names. Then, it loads the second line to get the column widths. Then, it uses `awk` to convert that file to CSV. What I'd prefer to do is find a program that automatically does that (can awk read the second line instead of requiring me to type in the column widths?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using GNU awk for `FIELDWIDTHS` and `\s/\S`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="," }
FNR==1 { names=$0; next }
FNR==2 {
    FIELDWIDTHS=""
    while ( match($0,/\S+\s*/) ) {
        FIELDWIDTHS = (FIELDWIDTHS ? FIELDWIDTHS " " : "") RLENGTH
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    $0 = names
}
{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        sub(/\s+$/,"",$i)
        printf "%s%s", $i, (i<NF?OFS:ORS)
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
Name,DOB,GENDER
JOHN DOE,19870130,M
MARY DOE,19850521,F
MARTY MCFLY,19790320,M
```

The above will work even if your first row contains spaces in the column names.