# Change only single occurence of space inbetween characters in bash

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I've an output as below:

```
NAME                UUID                                  TYPE            DEVICE 
Wired connection 1  e4249ef0-c4f0-3b64-8950-0c6be3edaca5  802-3-ethernet  enp0s3
```

I want to pick the device name if the type has `wireless` mentioned in it, using `awk`.

```
Expected output:
enp0s3
```

However one problem though. The `NAME` sometimes can be a single word in which case `awk` can recognize the `TYPE` and `DEVICE` as `field 3 & 4`.

```
awk '$3 ~ /wireless/{ print $4 }'
```

But The `NAME` sometimes has `spaces` in between, which I want to deal with first before applying `awk`, else its behaving erratically. if I can change the single spaces into "-", it solves my purpose.

Suggestions please.

Comment: What program outputs this information? Perhaps there's a flag you can pass it to print in an easier to parse format.

Comment: How do **you** identify the space-separated fields when the fields can contain spaces? tabs between fields? 2+ spaces between fields but only 1 at a time within fields? fixed width fields? something else?

Answer (score 4):

You said you want to print the "device name" so we don't know if you want to print the "DEVICE" field or the "NAME" field so we're all just guessing. That's why it's important to include the expected output in any question.

To print the DEVICE field:

```
awk '$(NF-1) ~ /wireless/ { print $NF }' file
```

To print the NAME field:

```
awk '$(NF-1) ~ /wireless/ { sub(/([[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+){3}[[:space:]]*$/,""); print }' file
```

It'll work no matter what white space your file contains between fields as long as only the NAME field can itself contain white space.

Comment: Calculations of `$NF` may be foiled by trailing whitespace on the line, as the OP has in his sample input. I thought this might work: `awk '{n=0} / $/ {n=1} $(NF-1-n) ~ /wireless/ { print $(NF-n) }'` .. but I'm apparently undercaffeinated this morning.

Comment: No, both scripts will work as-is even with trailing white space. I prescribe a double espresso :-).

Comment: Okay, I don't know what the heck is going on this morning. `printf 'foo\nbar \n' | awk '{print NF}'` gives me a pair of ones, but the same awk script gives me "5" and "7" on the OP's input data unless I trim the trailing whitespace. Thanks for the prescription doc, it's obviously time for my meds.

Comment: I can't imagine, unless you're explicitly setting the FS. With the default FS, in addition to using all contiguous white space as the field separator, awk ignores leading and trailing white space in each record when assigning the fields.

Comment: @EdMorton I edited my question to make it clear, I wanted the DEVICE field value, which your answer satisfies perfectly. Thanks

Comment: AH, got it, thanks to `od -c`. I have no idea how, but somehow I pasted a file with CRLF line endings after the trailing whitespace. Never mind, all's well. :)

Comment: @EdMorton : Unfortunately when I try to get the `NAME` field, the soultion still doesn't help. I get : `nmcli connection show | awk '$(NF-1) ~ /ethernet/ { sub(/([[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+){3}[[:space:]]*$/,"-"); print }'` output as `Wired connection 1  e4249ef0-c4f0-3b64-8950-0c6be3edaca5  802-3-ethernet  enp0s3`. Expected was `Wired-connection-1  e4249ef0-c4f0-3b64-8950-0c6be3edaca5  802-3-ethernet  enp0s3`

Comment: I don't see the difference in your comment between the output you got and the output you expected. If you're using a non-POSIX awk (e.g. nawk) then it may not recognize character classes so try replacing each `[:space:]` with `<blank>\t`, so, for example `[[:space:]]` becomes `[ \t]`. If you have a very old gawk you may need to add `--re-interval` at the front to enable `{3}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the first line to measure the start and end of the third field and then search that range of characters in subsequent lines for the pattern(s) you're interested in:

```
awk 'NR == 1 { start = index($0, $3); end = index($0, $4); next }
     substr($0, start, end - start) ~ /less/ { print $NF }' file
```

Comment: @Inian thanks I got confused by "device name" - I guess it's the DEVICE column as you say.

Comment: I wish I could revert back the comment I gave, I'm honestly not sure which column it is that OP wants :)

Answer (score 1):

First better test data (ie. with a match):

```
$ cat file
NAME                UUID                                  TYPE            DEVICE 
Wired connection 1  e4249ef0-c4f0-3b64-8950-0c6be3edaca5  802-3-ethernet  enp0s3 
Wireless conn       e4249ef0-c4f0-3b64-8950-0c6be3edaca5  802-3-wireless  enp0s3
```

Then, A GNU awk script based on @EdMorton's script for dealing with fixed width data (which I seem to need to use a lot, too bad I can't give it more ++, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31947741/4162356)):

```
awk '
FNR==1 {
    FIELDWIDTHS=""
    while ( match($0,/\S+\s*/) ) {
        FIELDWIDTHS = (FIELDWIDTHS ? FIELDWIDTHS " " : "") RLENGTH
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    next
}
$3~/wireless/ { print $4 }
' file
Wireless conn
```

**Edited** to print `$4` instead of `$1` as OP clarified the question.

Comment: I gave the same comment to Tom's answer, it is not clear if OP wanted to get the Device _name_ as in `$NF` or in `$1`

Comment: That is true, but _I want to pick the device name if the type_ would seem to refer to the $1, name not the device itself. But I'll add a disclaimer.

Comment: Ahem! Not sure still though!

Comment: _Disclaim'd_ ;D

Comment: Annnnd ... gawk-only. :-)  FIELDWIDTHS isn't part of the [one true awk](https://github.com/onetrueawk/awk).  (You mentioned Ed's GNU awk script, but didn't really nail things down for your own answer.)

Comment: We seem to have a tough crowd out there today. :D