# Using Awk to find Unique chars bought by a customer

Tags: awk

I have log files like this (it's only space between them but for readibility i changed that) :

```
Customer  Car             Bought
François  Nissan Pajero   28/05/2016
Matthew   Mercedes S      10/01/2019
Andrew    Peugeot 508     05/0/2000
Matthew   Toyota Hilux    02/10/2012
```

I need to make an awk script which display for each customer what car he has bought like this :

```
Matthew, car bought: Mercedes S,Toyota Hilux, number of cars: 2
Francois, car bought: Nissan Pjero, number of cars: 1
```

I'm not able to know how to do it.

I think i should create an array for Customer and one for the car and indexed it with the number of line

```
awk ' { Customer[NR]=$1; Car[NR]=$2} END {}'
```

What should i add in the END, i'm little perplexed

I thought doing this also:

```
awk ' { Customer[$1]=$2} END { for (i in Customer) print i,Customer[i]}'
```

The problem with this array, it will destroy the previous value of the car in the Customer indexed array.

Comment: We aren't a service that writes your program for you given only a specification. Show a specific technical problem you encountered while trying to solve it yourself, or at least enough of your own effort that we know what level of understanding you currently have so we know how much explanation to give.

Comment: (Also, someone answering this would need a better specification of the file format. Are the columns padded out with tabs or spaces? If it's spaces, are the padding widths guaranteed constant or can they change? If the column widths can change, are there any guarantees that *can* be used, such as knowing that there will always be at least two spaces between adjacent columns, and never more than one in data *within* a column?)

Comment: Hi, the colums are padded with space, always

Comment: That's one of four questions, the other three being specifically applicable *if* padding uses spaces.

Comment: (but thank you for the edit; I think this is an answerable question now, at least if one is willing to make assumptions about the input which those questions would bring into certainty; and have retracted my close vote).

Comment: Are you okay with non-awk answers?

Comment: This is an interesting date for sure `05/0/2000`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not worried about order of output(which should not be same as Input_file's 1st field) then could you please try following.

```
awk '
FNR>1{
  match($0,/ +.* +/)
  var=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"",var)
  a[$1]=(a[$1]?a[$1] OFS:"")var
  b[$1]++
}
END{
  for(i in a){
    print i","a[i]",number of cars: "b[i]
  }
}
'   Input_file
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** Adding solution which will provide output in same order of 1st field of Input_file.

```
awk '
FNR>1{
  if(!b[$1]++){
    c[++count]=$1
  }
  match($0,/ +.* +/)
  var=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"",var)
  a[$1]=(a[$1]?a[$1] OFS:"")var
  d[$1]++
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    print c[i]","a[c[i]]",number of cars: "d[c[i]]
  }
}
'   Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that each customer really does have a 1-word name as shown in your example and implied by your code (if not then we'd use fixed-width field parsing to identify the fields - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/31947741/1745001):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR>1 {
    gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"")
    cust = $1
    gsub(/^[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+$/,"")
    cars[cust,++numCars[cust]] = $0
    custs[cust]
}
END {
    for (cust in custs) {
        printf "%s, car bought: ", cust
        for (carNr=1; carNr<=numCars[cust]; carNr++) {
            printf "%s,", cars[cust,carNr]
        }
        printf " number of cars: %d\n", numCars[cust]
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
Andrew, car bought: Peugeot 508, number of cars: 1
Matthew, car bought: Mercedes S,Toyota Hilux, number of cars: 2
François, car bought: Nissan Pajero, number of cars: 1
```

With the above if a given customer buys the same type of car (e.g. Peugeot 508) on multiple dates they will all be listed/counted in the output.

Answer (score 0):

For this data I would use `Splunk`.  It can analyze up to 500MB each day for free.  You can get whatever reports and graph anything you like.