# Formatting the output of a sql query and creating a csv

Tags: unix, awk, sed

The current output that i have from a sql query is

```
database_name   database_size     unallocated_space   reserved      data          index_size    unused
-------------- ------------------ ------------------  ------------- ------------- ------------- ------------- 
 TEST            22200.00 MB            3160.41 MB      9256544 KB    6597072 KB    1559384 KB    1100088 KB
```

Trying to create a csv in the format

```
database_name,database_size,unallocated_space,reserved,data,index_size,unused
Test,22200.00 MB,3160.41 MB,9256544 KB,6597072 KB,1559384 KB,1100088 KB
```

Output that I am currently getting

```
database_name,database_size,unallocated_space
Test,22200.00,MB,3160.41,MB,9256544,KB,6597072,KB,1559384,KB,1100088,KB
```

with

```
echo "database_name,database_size,unallocated_space" > $outfile
awk -F " " '{print $1","$2","$3",$4","$5","$6","$7}' $readFile  >> $outfile
```

where readfile is the file containing the sql query output and outfile is the csv.

Comment: Kindly do wrap your samples and codes in CODE TAGS in your question and let us know then.

Comment: You could probably modify this answer by @EdMorton to suit your needs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31947741/4162356 Which database, are you using, BTW?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this `awk`, first condition prints the header, second one prints the fields with numbers and MB together.

```
> awk -v OFS=, 'NR==1{$1=$1;print;next} NF==5{print $1, $2" "$3, $4" "$5}' file
database_name,database_size,unallocated_space
Test,100.00 MB,200 MB
```

Or an alternative `awk`, from @Cyrus (based on the number of spaces in your input).

```
> awk 'NR!=2{$1=$1; print}' FS='  +' OFS=',' file
database_name,database_size,unallocated_space,
Test,100.00 MB,200 MB
```

**Note:** in both commands, `$1=$1` is an idiom to force `awk` split to fields and recalculate the output, so it prints using the new field separator.

---

Modified for the updated input:

```
awk -OFS, 'NR==1{$1=$1;print;next} NF==13{print $1,$2" "$3,...<etc until 12-13> }' file
```

Comment: or alternatively with GNU awk: `awk 'NR!=2{$1=$1; print}' FS='  +' OFS=',' file`. I assume that in JSS's question the many spaces on the right are not part of the output.

Comment: The above works just fine but if we have another row that has is appended to the sql output the above is not able to fetch that ```database_name   database_size      unallocated_space
-------------- ------------------ ------------------
TEST            22200.00 MB            3160.41 MB
reserved      data          index_size    unused
------------- ------------- ------------- -------------
9256544 KB    6597072 KB    1559384 KB    1100088 KB
``` Is it possible to tweak the above somehow?

Comment: @JSS [Chameon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/361691) are strongly discouraged. You asked a question, got some answers, and accepted an answer. If you need something additional then just ask a new followup question.

Comment: @Ed Morton perhaps you should be awarded a badge for chameleon hunting, also I have to train myself on that.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just change your SQL query, somethin like:

```
Select concat(database_name, ",", database_size, ",", ...) ...
```

Like this, you don't need to do any reformatting afterwards.

Beware, I have written "concat", I'm not sure about the correct name of the concatenation function.