# How to upload text file in postgresql which have multiple space between columns?

Tags: linux, database, postgresql, shell

Here file1 & file2 5 column but file2 have 4 columns data available.
I am not able to upload/import file in table because they have no delimiter.
Table total column 5 & every file should be **upload/import in same table**.

Every column's value has **fixed length** like column1 has 1,10; column2 has 14,12; column3 has 30,2; column4 has 41,8; column5 has 54,4.

**> I use PostgreSQL Database Server. What should I do? Please help me.**

### **file1**

```
88056846     465             L          4.009        AB3C
88056846     465             L                       AB3C
88056846     465             L          4.009        AB3C
```

### **file2**

```
88056846     465                        4.009        AB3C
88056846     465                        4.009        AB3C
88056846     465                        4.009        AB3C
```

**[enter image description here is real view file1 & file2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pg3qE.png)**

Comment: I think pgloader has support for such formats.

Answer (score 1):

You could, for example, use GNU awk to convert the fixed width file to better form before loading:

```
$ gawk '
BEGIN {
    FIELDWIDTHS="8 8 14 15 12"  # estimated from your second sample data
    OFS=","
}
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)          # loop all fields
        gsub(/^ *| *$/,"",$i)   # trim space
    print                       # output
}' file
```

Output of the first file:

```
88056846,465,,4.009,AB3C
88056846,465,,4.009,AB3C
88056846,465,,4.009,AB3C
```

If your data has some sort of header, you don't need to estimate the field widths but use this: [Fixed width to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31947383/fixed-width-to-csv).

**Edited per comment:**

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    OFS="|"
}
{
    a[++c]=substr($0,1,10)
    a[++c]=substr($0,14,12)
    a[++c]=substr($0,30,2)
    a[++c]=substr($0,41,8)
    a[++c]=substr($0,54,4)

    for(i=1;i<=c;i++) {
        gsub(/^ *| *$/,"",a[i])
        printf "%s%s",a[i],(i<c?OFS:ORS)
    }
    c=0
}' file
```

Comment: Thank you @James Brown for your attention.

I am not able to get accurate result. 
Is it possible to set **{postion:length}** like this ${line:1:10} ${line:14:12} ${line:30:2} ${line:41:8} ${line:54:4}?
Also I wist to set **"|" instead of ","** and **script** will run automatically in all file.
Need your kind response.
Thank you once again.